# Give priority to group inside regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want my output to be what's inside *var data = "THIS";*, to do so I've manage to do this:

```
var plaintext = fs.readFileSync( process.argv[ 1 ] ).toString();
var regex = new RegExp("var\\ data\\ =\\ \"(.{0,})\";", "g", "y");
var regex2 = new RegExp("\"(.{0,})\"", "g");
var info = JSON.parse(plaintext.match(regex)[0].match(regex2)[0]);
```

Is there any way to have only one regular expression, and compact the code into 2 or 3 lines?

Comment: Not sure I get this right, but ``var plaintext = "var data = \"foobardoobar\";";
var regex = new RegExp("var data = \"(.{0,})\";");
console.log(plaintext.match(regex)[1]);`` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
plaintext.match(/var\s+data\s*=\s*"(.*)";/)[1]
```

**Update**: This regex will also match strings that contain escaped quotes, e.g. `"\"foo\""` as long as these quotes aren't followed by a semicolon. For this to work, the closing quote must be immediately followed by a semicolon.

As an alternative, you could also exclude double quotes from the matched string (Use `[^"]*` instead of `.*`) and leave out the semicolon from the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
var matches = plaintext.match(/var data = "([^"]+)"/);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hy8epp5/